# Disable autofollow hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref

EDIT: This topic is related to a bug in my pdf reader `Foxit 4.3.1`. 
So the Question should be more: "How to get this `MWE` working in Foxit?"

How can solve that hyperlinks are not auto followed?
Klicking on `\nameref{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}` jumps to `\subsection*{Bla}` but it should link to `\paragraph{\nameref{subsec:sevice_depencies}}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,ngerman,numbers=noenddot, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Bla}
\label{subsec:sevice_depencies}
\newpage
\paragraph{\nameref{subsec:sevice_depencies}}
\label{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}
\newpage
\nameref{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I get the desired behaviour with your code, clicking on the reference on page 3 leads to the paragraph on page 2.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. could this possible a problem with my pdf viewer? Using Foxit 4.3.1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Damn, right. It is a bug in foxit. Working fine in Win8 reader.

Comment: @Admins Didn't know If this topic should be open or deleted cause the problem seems more application related than tex related

Answer (score 4):

The link in the paragraph title can be disabled by the start form of `\nameref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,ngerman,numbers=noenddot, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Bla}
\label{subsec:sevice_depencies}
\newpage
\paragraph{\nameref*{subsec:sevice_depencies}}
\label{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}
\newpage
\nameref{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}

\end{document}
```

If only the nested link in the latest `\nameref` should be disabled, it becomes a little more complex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,ngerman,numbers=noenddot, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Bla}
\label{subsec:sevice_depencies}
\newpage
\paragraph{\nameref{subsec:sevice_depencies}}
\label{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}
\newpage
\hyperref[par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep]{%
  \begin{NoHyper}%
    \nameref*{par:SotaOtrsitsmEvalCorrDep}%
  \end{NoHyper}%
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, but I do not want to disable the link, I want only hat the third link links the the second and not to the first.